# How can I change the name of a windows user on my computer without creating a new local user?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user, username

I've been trying to find a way to change the name of a windows user on my windows 10 computer.

I want to do this because it cut off the last letter of my name. Just say my name is "George", it named the user as "georg".

How can I change the name of the user without making a new local user?

Comment: The "duplicate" was from two years ago and it does not work the same way now from a fresh install.

Comment: @John - The answer to the duplicate is absolutely accurate.  Furthermore, it’s absolutely possible to change a user’s profile name, I have done it many times.  One can use the process of unlinking a Microsoft Account to do that.  I submitted an answer to this effect many years ago (Windows 8) but it is still applicable to Windows 10

Comment: I do not believe so. I rebuilt an Insider machine and the main points of the article above did not allow me to change my profile name. I tried many things.

Comment: @John - Do the following: 1. Create a user linked to a Microsoft Account.  2. Take note of the user profile directory. 3. Unlink the Microsoft Account.  4. When prompted for the name of the profile change the value. 5. Logout of the account. 6. log back into the account.  You can change the value to what the new username will be, by doing that your username and profile directory will match, I have done this on every single version of Windows 10 including the current Insider Preview builds; I cannot for the life of me find the answer I submitted 6 years ago (that still works)

Comment: I left my machine the way it was as I did not wish to tamper with the Microsoft Account. The downvoted answer alluded to similar steps. Too late for the computer now and I just left it the way it is because the display name is correct.  I have a production machine with the same Microsoft Account and tampering with the one (at the time) gave errors. It truly was not worth it.

Comment: @John - i have seamlessly disconnected and connected a Microsoft Account many times.  I have changed the user profile directory many times using the process I described